# First occurrence of a command

Tags: macros, conditionals, grouping

I'm writing some macros that need to behave differently after first occurrence. I decided to use the `etoolbox` package's `toggle`. My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{SL}

\newcommand{\SL}{%
  \textit{SL}%
  \nottoggle{SL}{~first}{~second}%
  \toggletrue{SL}% switches to true after first occurrence!
}

\begin{document}
A footnote.\footnote{\SL}\par
\SL \par
\SL \par
\SL
\end{document}
```

As an output I get the following:

[image: MWE]

The problem, as you can see, is that when using the command in a footnote, the toggle does not occur. (Should the image not be clear enough, the footnote reads "1 SL first".)

What is going on in here? (I tried TeX's `\newif` with the same result, by the way.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is hidden in the [package documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf):

> This command [...] may be prefixed with `\global`.

The meaning of this is that usually `\toggletrue` will work *locally*, that is the setting is undone by the enclosing group. `\footnote` here defines a group. So you need to use

```
\global\toggletrue{SL}% switches to true after first occurrence!
```

in your macro to make sure the switch is always set globally.

[image]

Comment: Just for curiosity---is there another way to accomplish this without toggles or booleans?

Comment: Another trick which is common with TeX is something like `\newcommand{\SL}{\textit{SL}~first\renewcommand\SL{\textit{SL}~second}}`. ...although a global version is easier with plain TeX than with basic LaTeX: `\gdef\SL{\textit{SL}~first\gdef\SL{\textit{SL}~second}}`.

Comment: Thanks! That's cool. I wasn't aware that one could redefine a command from within the very command!