# How to typeset first occurrence of a string differently than the later ones?

Tags: etoolbox

My question is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59272/first-occurrence-of-a-command) but I need a solution depending on the input. I'd like to have a command `\propername{}`, which writes the very first occurrence of the first argument in italic, otherwise normal.

I tried to solve it with the `etoolbox`-package, so far without success.

```tex
\newcommand{\propername}[1]{%
    \providetoggle{propername#1}
    \iftoggle{propername#1}{not first: #1}
    \nottoggle{propername#1}{first: #1}
    \toggletrue{propername#1}% switches to true after first occurrence!
}
```

`\propername{foobar}` output `first: foobarpropernamefoobar`

In the end I'd like to have something like this:

Input: `\propername{foobar} bar \propername{foobar}`

Output: "*foobar* bar foobar"

The challenge is that I need a toggle for each possible input value.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a wrapper for these commands. This defines the command to print the text in italic *and* globally redefines the same command to print it normally. No need to define toggles for each such command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\makespecialcommand}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{\textit{#2}\gdef#1{#2}}%
}

\makespecialcommand{\foo}{foo}
\makespecialcommand{\baz}{baz}

\begin{document}

Here \foo\ is called and \foo\ is called again.

\begin{quote}
Now \baz\ is called in an environment.
\end{quote}

And now \baz\ is called again.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to pursue the `\propername` strategy, globally define an internal macro when the command is executed the first time (when the internal macro is still undefined).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\propername}[1]{%
  \ifcsname\detokenize{#1}@used\endcsname
    #1%
  \else
    \textit{#1}%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname\detokenize{#1}@used\endcsname\empty
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

Here \propername{foo} is called and \propername{foo} is called again.

\begin{quote}
Now \propername{baz} is called in an environment.
\end{quote}

And now \propername{baz} is called again.

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

You can extend the code to count the occurrences.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\propername}[1]{%
  \ifcsname\detokenize{#1}@used\endcsname
    #1%
    \global\expandafter\xdef\csname\detokenize{#1}@used\endcsname{%
      \the\numexpr\csname\detokenize{#1}@used\endcsname+1\relax
    }%
  \else
    \textit{#1}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname\detokenize{#1}@used\endcsname{1}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\nameoccurred}[1]{%
  \ifcsname\detokenize{#1}@used\endcsname
    ``#1 occurred \csname\detokenize{#1}@used\endcsname\space times''
  \else
    ``#1 didn't appear''
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

Here \propername{foo} is called and \propername{foo} is called again.

\begin{quote}
Now \propername{baz} is called in an environment.
\end{quote}

And now \propername{baz} is called again and \propername{baz} again.

\nameoccurred{foo}

\nameoccurred{baz}

\nameoccurred{gnu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP will have to define many commands manually this way.

Comment: @Niranjan My idea is that it's better, but I also provided code for the other strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with Tex, but I could solve it like this:

```tex
% Writes the first occurrence of a given word in italic, otherwise normal.
\newcommand{\propername}[1]{%
    \providebool{propername#1}
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{propername#1}}
        % not first occurrence
        {#1}
        % first occurrence
        {\textit{#1} \setboolean{propername#1}{true}}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the counter mechanism. The following code:

1. defines a new command `\myitalic` which first checks if the word you have passed as an argument is used for the first time or not, if yes it italicizes it.
2. then defines our actual command which uses the above definition. Here we define a counter of our desired proper name *only if it doesn't exist*. The emphasized part is important, otherwise at every instance of that word the same counter is defined, which produces an error. We set the value of that newly defined counter to 0 in this if-condition. Because of this; the text is italicized when it is used for the first time and it is printed in the normal font otherwise. For the later we increase the value of our counter by one unit each time it gets used. The proper noun escapes the if-condition from the second usage because of this.

PS: Not something that you asked for, but we can print how many times a proper noun has been used with [the mighty `\the`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38680/174620).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myitalic}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{#1}=0%
    \textit{#1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\propername}[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname
    \relax
  \else
    \newcounter{#1}%
  \fi
  \myitalic{#1}%
  \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\propername{foobaz}
\propername{foobaz}
\propername{foobaz}
\propername{foobaz}
\propername{foobaz}.

`foobaz' was used \thefoobaz\ times.

\propername{bazfoo}
\propername{bazfoo}
\propername{bazfoo}.

`bazfoo' was used \thebazfoo\ times.
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

A major benefit of this code is it doesn't require any package. Every thing in it is plain-LaTeX. :)

Comment: There are several counters available, but this is not a reason to abuse them for just setting them >0 (unless you really want to count their appearance). Macros are cheaper.

Comment: Can you explain any problem-cases with this approach?

Comment: I didn't understand "but this is not a reason to abuse them for just setting them >0". I didn't set it to zero. I just checked it's value and set a conditional _if_ it's zero.

Comment: No real problem, except wasting resources. You basically get different behavior if the counter is 0 or greater than 0, don't you? If the number of times is not needed, you're wasting a counter just to set it greater than 0.

Comment: Okay, I would say everything in the code has been used, so nothing is really getting wasted as far as this answer is concerned. If the OP doesn't want counting at all, then maybe your answer is a better alternative.